# ImportError: No module django_nose

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-nose

I following [this pluralsight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=docker-ansible-continuous-delivery&author=justin-menga&name=docker-ansible-continuous-delivery-m2&clip=3&mode=live) and running into this error everytime I run the command:

```
python manage.py test --settings=todobackend.settings.test
```

I'm new to the Django framework; Could the problem be that my django version (1.9.0) only supports python 3.x and not 2.x?

```
python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

***Click on pic to see larger, clearer image.***

[image]

[image]

Comment: whats the output of `pip2 freeze|grep django`?

Comment: Django 1.9 *does* support Python 2. Django 2.0 is the first version that only supports Python 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as if you have not installed `django-nose` in your virtual environment. You can install it with:

```
pip install django-nose
```

Comment: Thanks so much Alasair, after installing django-nose in my virtual env, I ran into this other error: manage.py: error: no such option: --with-spec
A quick google revealed that I needed this additional package, Pinocchio, which I installed with pip install Pinnocchio and reran my cmd, python manage.py test --settings=todobackend.settings.test, and it worked and passed all tests. Just for future references for anyone running into this issue; thanks again !